# Не работает json_decode()

Tags: php, json

есть такой код:

```
$arParams = array("keys"=>"vals");
$key = md5('BqxhTvmEhbAKdG6P'."2");
$m_params = urlencode(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, json_encode($arParams), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
```

Я беру массив и ключ, с помощью ключа кодирую этот массив, сначала через `json_encode`, потом через `mcrypt_encrypt`, после через `base64_encode` и `urlencode`.

Теперь хочу вернуть все как было, пишу вот так:

```
$a = urldecode($m_params);
$a = base64_decode($a);
$a = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$a,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

В `$a` у меня должна быть корректная json строка, но `json_decode($a)` возвращает `NULL`.
В поисках проблемы я написал вот такой код:

```
var_dump($a); 
echo("<br>");
var_dump(json_decode($a));
echo("<br>");
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($a));
echo("<br>");
 switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - Ошибок нет';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Достигнута максимальная глубина стека';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Некорректные разряды или несоответствие режимов';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Некорректный управляющий символ';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Синтаксическая ошибка, некорректный JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Некорректные символы UTF-8, возможно неверно закодирован';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Неизвестная ошибка';
        break;
    }
```

Вот что получаю на выходе:

```
string(32) "{"keys":"vals"}"
NULL
string(5) "ASCII"
- Некорректный управляющий символ
```

Что это значит, как решить проблему? Я подозреваю, что в строке есть ещё какие-то данные, помимо видимых, потому что если просто взять и преобразовать массив в json, то строка получается в 2 раза меньше, хотя кодировка такая-же (ASCII):

var_dump(json_encode($arParams));

```
string(15) "{"keys":"vals"}"
```

Comment: в конце сделай $a = trim($a)

Comment: и вообще mcrypt_encrypt Эта функция объявлена УСТАРЕВШЕЙ, начиная с PHP 7.1.0. Использовать эту функции крайне не рекомендуется.

Comment: и вот похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758240/php-decrypt-string-with-mcrypt-rijndael-256